# The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am new in asp.net and my company had a project and all of this project devolopers leave from here , no one know about the project. I need to update it.
Actually all are configured locally in my windowsXP system. database ,iis,project file all are here.

while I am using webrequest I get an error 
"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
the error and code are here
Please help me
The error is

```
Server Error in '/ava-006' Application.
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Source Error:

```
Line 50:         End If
Line 51: 
Line 52:         wResp = wr.GetResponse
Line 53:         sr = New System.IO.StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream)
Line 54:         Shtml = sr.ReadToEnd
```

Source File: F:\Prajeesh\ava-006\lead.report.aging.aspx.vb    Line: 52

Stack Trace:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +5375997
   ava_006.lead_report_aging.GetReport(String strFormat, String strWeek) in F:\Prajeesh\ava-006\lead.report.aging.aspx.vb:52
   ava_006.lead_report_aging.btnView_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\Prajeesh\ava-006\lead.report.aging.aspx.vb:73
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +107
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3436


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3623; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618
```

AND the code I use is

```
<pre lang="vb">Function GetReport(ByVal strFormat As String, ByVal strWeek As String) As String
        Dim wr As WebRequest
        Dim wResp As WebResponse
        Dim sr As StreamReader
        Dim Shtml As String
        If InStr(Request.ServerVariables(&quot;path_info&quot;), &quot;ava-006&quot;) &gt; 0 Then
            wr = HttpWebRequest.Create(&quot;http://&quot; &amp; Request.ServerVariables(&quot;server_name&quot;) &amp; &quot;/ava-006/lead.report.agingsub.aspx?pFormat=&quot; &amp; strFormat &amp; &quot;&amp;pWeek=&quot; &amp; strWeek)
        Else
            wr = HttpWebRequest.Create(&quot;http://&quot; &amp; Request.ServerVariables(&quot;server_name&quot;) &amp; &quot;/lead.report.agingsub.aspx?pFormat=&quot; &amp; strFormat &amp; &quot;&amp;pWeek=&quot; &amp; strWeek)
        End If
        wResp = wr.GetResponse
        sr = New System.IO.StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream)
        Shtml = sr.ReadToEnd
        GetReport = Shtml
    End Function</pre>
```

Comment: I think that the error is on the server that you try to get the data and not on this code. So you need to check if your remote server that you actually try to get the data is working, and the data is on the place that you ask them for. This is what you need to check if its working. server_name//ava-006/lead.report.agingsub.aspx

Answer (score 1):

error is in your page **lead.report.agingsub.aspx**
when its pass **pFormat** and **pWeek** its throw error so
its display error 500 because **wr.GetResponse** return error from page **lead.report.agingsub.aspx**

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point on your btnView_Click and see where the exception happens.